# Grails tab order

Tags: grails, tab-ordering

I was recently given a project to modify and I know very little about Grails.  All I need to do is edit the code to make it so the user does not have to use a mouse, so I need to set the tab order.  How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the tabindex property on the fields in the .gsp files, just like an HTML page.

Comment: Okay so I set the tab index and it works great in firefox/chrome but in IE it still jumps around?